# What is the empty dictionary used for in the code?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing practice problems in python on Leetcode (still learning). This is the problem: 
Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

my code is

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        dict = {}
        for counter, i in enumerate(nums):
            a = target- i
            if a in dict:
                return (dict[a], counter)
            dict[i] = counter
```

It runs fine and passes all the tests however I found a common reason this works is for the dict = {}
What is the reason for this dictionary and how does this code recognize cases for (3,3) target = 6 where there are duplicates and index matters. A basic run down of why the code works would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary stores as keys the numbers in the list with their index as a value.

For example:

```
[2, 7, 11, 15] -> {'2':0, '7':1, '11':2, '15':3}
```

There is never a duplicate inserted, if the same number appears twice, the index will be replaced with the new index where it appears.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of duplicate, it is important to test all value on the first list, and to store index on a separated dict in order to be sur that you will never test in dictionnary the actually tested value.

By using a dictionnary in order to find the index of the right number, you can't store duplicate.
Since in dictionnary you can't have 2 values with the same key, if duplicate, you just change the old index with the new one.

For example, if `dict == {'3': 0, '2':1}` and the tested value is 2, the `dict == {'3': 0, '2':2}`.

And if the target is reach by duplicate number (`2+2` for target `4` for example), nothing is stored cause of the return in the `if a in dict: return (dict[a], counter)`